# New tagged questions not autoloading

Tags: bug, live-refresh

Earlier the link to the tagged questions looked like

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-name

But now from today its been changed to

https://stackoverflow.com/?tags=tag-name

Earlier the `newest` questions used to auto load, but now the new questions are not loading automatically. To see the new questions, now I need to refresh the page. It is a bit irritating as earlier we used to get notifications for the same!

Hope this problem gets solved soon!

Comment: Switch back to the old nav system. The new one is broken.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Did you opt in? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259220/new-navigation-alpha-2-released The option is network-wide